# ControlFormat.Enabled property throwing error

Tags: excel, vba, exception, dropdown

I want to lock a dynamic drop down in VBA, but face an issue while trying to set the `Dropdown.ControlFormat.Enabled` property.

```
ddlIsNegative.TopLeftCell.Locked = True
Set lbcf = ddlIsNegative.ControlFormat
If (lbcf.value = 2) Then
    ddlIsNegative.ControlFormat.Enabled = False
End If
```

While setting `ddlIsNegative.ControlFormat.Enabled` property, it throws the error

> unable to set enabled property of Group Object class

Comment: What kind of dropdown-object is your "ddlIsNegative"? How did you implement it?

Comment: @Asger - I got solution and posted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to resolved this issue by adding additional exceptions.

```
Err.Clear
        ddlIsNegative.TopLeftCell.Locked = True
        On Error GoTo errExit
        ddlIsNegative.ControlFormat.Enabled = False
errExit:
```